# Using Vert.x package io.vertx.ext.auth.kerberos.KerberosOptions is not permitted as it's no longer available

Tags: kerberos, vert.x, gssapi, vert.x-webclient

I wanted to update unused code that is now required in order for a Java Vert.x application to authenticate to Kerberos protected api endpoint. However the kerberos packages ( io.vertx.ext.auth.kerberos ) are no longer recognised. My application runs in a Kubernetes namespace where the the k5b5.conf file is mounted to the pod that would run a variation of below class that is simplified.

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Promise;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpClient;
import io.vertx.ext.auth.AuthOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.auth.User;
import io.vertx.ext.auth.kerberos.KerberosAuthOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.auth.kerberos.KerberosOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.HttpRequest;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClientOptions;

public class KerberosVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) {
        WebClient webClient = createWebClient();

        HttpRequest<String> request = webClient.getAbs("https://example-kerberos-protected-api.com/resource");

        request.send(response -> {
            if (response.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("Response: " + response.result().bodyAsString());
                startPromise.complete();
            } else {
                response.cause().printStackTrace();
                startPromise.fail(response.cause());
            }
        });
    }

    private WebClient createWebClient() {
        WebClientOptions options = new WebClientOptions()
                .setSsl(true)
                .setUseAlpn(true)
                .setTrustAll(true); 

        AuthOptions authOptions = new KerberosAuthOptions()
                .setKrb5Config("/etc/krb5.conf"); // Path to  krb5.conf file

        KerberosOptions kerberosOptions = new KerberosOptions()
                .setAuthOptions(authOptions);

        return WebClient.create(vertx, options)
                .authKerberos(kerberosOptions);
    }
}
```

Would expect methods createWebClient to return a Vert.x Webclient instance but class fails to compile.

Comment: Which module provided Kerberos auth?

Comment: @tsegismont, it's from this dependency  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-auth-common</artifactId>
    <version>${vertx.version}</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Thanks, which version?